# Which parameter to use to specify the relay in a CAN line communication?

Tags: current, circuit-design, can, solid-state-relay

I need to use SSRs (solid state relays) to comute lines of comunication to a vehicular OBD-II interface. I will use SSRs to choose wich lines will be used at the pins of the connector. The lines wil not be commuted during comunication. The signals I need to comute are CAN. 
The CAN transceiver is the SNx5HVD251, so, In order to specify the SSR electrically, I tried to very the maximum current the SNx5HVD251 supports. In the datasheet says, in the operational conditions, that the driver output current, IOH is at most 50mA or -50mA. But There is another parameter, Short-circuit steady-state output current that, accordingly with datasheet, is 200mA.

So, this is my doubt, wich parameter to use ?

Comment: You "need" to use SSRs, or you "decided" to use first thing that came to your mind and now you don't know what to do with it?

Comment: @Maple I chose SSRs because of the smallest size, I'm designing a new version of a hardware that used electrical mechanical (EM) relays.

Comment: Shouldn't you choose electrical components by their electrical function first, and size second? Like for example check out digital and analog switches, bus multiplexers etc. which also happen to be _much_ smaller than SSRs.

Comment: @Maple it is a good advice. The choice about SSRs was made based on hardwares in the market. Also, this way would be easier to test because initially, before designing the new hardware, I would just swap relays on the old hardware by making some modifications.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have more than one CAN buses coming to the board and you select one of them dynamically. If this is your case then I want to make a suggestion: If I were you, I would use one transceiver (e.g. SN65HVD251Q) per line and select D and R pins of them through a MUX.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have others signals, but the CAN signals can go to different pins. The other signals I can estimate the amout of current, they are no greather than 5mA. But the I have doubt about how to specify the amount of current in the CAN lines.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  The hardware that I'm designing doesn't have tranceiver, the transceiver is part of an external hardware. The hardware that I'm designing is intend to realize the comutation to the pins to allow communication between the hardware with the tranceiver and a third device.

Comment: If you don't break the signals during communication, you can put pretty any kind of component there, since switching times won't be critical. Getting a relay or solid state that can drive > 1A should be no problem, although absolute maximum rating for CAN is roughly 200mA, give or take.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you! But, about this absolute maximum rating of 200mA, how do you have this number?

Comment: I believe it would be the typical short circuit current of CANH/CANL, at least on MCP2551. The actual max characteristics of dominant level during operation is 75mA. But obviously, design with margins. There's no reason for you to pick a solid state that can only drive a couple of hundred mA.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I'm in doubt with two, one of them has 100mA of on-state current and the other has 1.3A(This was the SSR with the best price and current above 200mA). The second has almost the double of the price of the first. If max characteristics of dominant level during operation is 75mA, considering a 100mA  on-state current would be sufficient, no ?  33% of margin does'nt seems to be so bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several parameters of interest;

1. Impedance of transmission lines and terminators
2. Signal currents
3. Short cct. currents to  +12, -7V
4. Internal Switch Ron or RdsOn
5. Off switch capacitance.

The currents usually follow Ohm's Law if you have an accurate model for Ron and drive levels  for PFET and NFET to short voltage for Hi and Lo.
 [image]

The CANBUS is already a 30 port MUX with stubs on a bus terminated by 120 Ohms.

But you may want to consider all options such as FETs and miniature Reed Relays to MUX to many busses.

**Start with good Specs.**